# How to return highest id value from a table via join with eloquent Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have two tables that share a relationship users and log table. I’m trying to query the users table and get the record from log with the highest id value

so far this is what I have that’s returning duplicate entries:

```
  $students = User::with([
        'course' => function ($query) {
            $query->get(['id', 'name']);
        }
    ])
        ->join('log', 'users.id', '=', 'log.user_id')
        ->where('log.event', 1)
        ->orderBy('log.id', 'desc')
        ->where('users.verified', 1)
        ->get(['users.*', 'log.id AS logid']);
```

Ideally, I want the last inserted record from the log table for each user

```
groupBy('user_id')
```

returns the first record

Comment: MAX() in mysql  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html for the largest number, and last insert id for the last id inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $students = User::with([
        'course' => function ($query) {
            $query->get(['id', 'name']);
        }
    ])
        ->join('log', 'users.id', '=', 'log.user_id')
        ->where('log.event', 1)
        ->whereRaw('log.id = (select max(`id`) from log where `user_id` = users.id )')
        ->where('users.verified', 1)
        ->get(['users.*', 'log.id AS logid', 'log.user_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close to, only you need to use [limit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

```
  ->where('users.verified', 1)
  ->take(1) // add this to get only a single record
  ->get(['users.*', 'log.id AS logid']);
```

Try the below solution with 1 more where condition without `groupBy`

```
$students = User::with([
    'course' => function ($query) {
        $query->get(['id', 'name']);
    }
])
->join('log', 'users.id', '=', 'log.user_id')
->where('log.event', 1)
->orderBy('log.id', 'desc')
->where('users.verified', 1)
->where('log.id',DB::raw("SELECT MAX(id) FROM log WHERE log.user_id = users.id")) // get the max id value
->get(['users.*', 'log.id AS logid']);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well but here's what happens: it limits the whole result set to 1 result. What i'd like to happen is for the associated log records to be limited to just 1

Comment: Are you using `groupBy('user_id')`?

Comment: No, not anymore...i'm not using it

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion led me to the solution. See the answer below